# Multiply normally distributed random vector by a unital random vector

Tags: matrices, statistics, probability-distributions

Today I read a paper where one of the steps looks like the following:

$$x'Z(y/\|y\|)\sim N(0,n/\|y\|^2).$$
Here x' is a 1 by n vector with iid entries randomly selected between -1 and 1 (follows 2Bernoulli(0.5)-1).
Z is a n by m matrix where each entries are from iid N(0,1).
y is a m by 1 vector with iid entries from the following distribution: $(1-\epsilon)\delta_0+ \epsilon/2\delta_a+\epsilon/2\delta_{-a}$, where  $\delta_{a}$ is a function with 1 at a and zero everywhere else.

Currently, I think x'Z gives us a 1 by m  vector with each entry following N(0,n).
However, I can't figure out how to multiply $y/\|y\|$ into this vector.
Intuitively, since it is a unit vector, it seems like a $1/\sqrt{n}$ term emerges naturally from the vector since sum of the square of terms has to be one. but I don't know how to make multiplication rigorous.

Any help is very much appreciated.